# checkinstall doesn't copy files to destination

Tags: installation, ntfs

I am installing ntfs-3g from its source code "Stable Source Release 2009.11.14". After "./configure", "make", I called "checkinstall -D make install". It is at this time I got errors:

```
Making install in libntfs-3g  
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ting/Desktop/ntfs-3g-2009.11.14/libntfs-3g'  
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ting/Desktop/ntfs-3g-2009.11.14/libntfs-3g'  
test -z "/usr/local/lib" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib"  
 /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c  'libntfs-3g.la' '/usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.la'  
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/libntfs-3g.so.71.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.so.71.0.0  
(cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libntfs-3g.so.71.0.0 libntfs-3g.so.71 || { rm -f libntfs-3g.so.71 && ln -s libntfs-3g.so.71.0.0 libntfs-3g.so.71; }; })  
(cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libntfs-3g.so.71.0.0 libntfs-3g.so || { rm -f libntfs-3g.so && ln -s libntfs-3g.so.71.0.0 libntfs-3g.so; }; })  
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/libntfs-3g.lai /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.la  
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/libntfs-3g.a /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.a  
chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.a  
chmod: changing permissions of `/usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.a': No such file or directory  
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1  
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ting/Desktop/ntfs-3g-2009.11.14/libntfs-3g'  
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ting/Desktop/ntfs-3g-2009.11.14/libntfs-3g'  
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

But running "make install" instead of "checkinstall -D make install" is successful. After running "make install", with its generated `/usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.a', "checkinstall -D make install" is also successful. I just wonder why "checkinstall -D make install" itself does not work?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that checkinstall requires the command to be taken into quotes like this:

```
checkinstall -D "make install"
```